# Unable to upload files into S3 bucket through iOS 11.4.1 (AWS-IOS-SDK-2.6.24)

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk-ios

I'm facing issue while uploading the files on AWS S3 bucket (using AWS-IOS-SDK-2.6.24) from iOS 11.4.1 devices. The same code works fine for iOS 9.x.x.

Mostly I'm getting timeout error:

```
    Request headers:
    {
        "Content-Type" = "application/x-amz-json-1.1";
        Host = "cognito-identity.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com";
        "User-Agent" = "aws-sdk-iOS/2.6.24 iOS/11.4 en_US";
        "X-Amz-Date" = 20180718T080347Z;
        "X-Amz-Target" = "AWSCognitoIdentityService.GetCredentialsForIdentity";
    }
    2018-07-18 12:03:47:866 AWR_Vehicle_Recieving[672:656549] Request body:
    {"IdentityId":"ap-south-1:999df51b-5cef-49aa-a566-369a4af76c37"}
    2018-07-18 12:03:51.026657+0400 AWR_Vehicle_Recieving[672:656552] [] tcp_timers tcp[2] retransmit SYN 3
    2018-07-18 12:03:51.288385+0400 AWR_Vehicle_Recieving[672:656552] [] tcp_timers tcp[3] retransmit SYN 3
    2018-07-18 12:03:52.033153+0400 AWR_Vehicle_Recieving[672:656551] [] tcp_timers tcp[2] retransmit SYN 4
    2018-07-18 12:03:52.290329+0400 AWR_Vehicle_Recieving[672:656551] [] tcp_timers tcp[3] retransmit SYN 4
    2018-07-18 12:03:53.034734+0400 AWR_Vehicle_Recieving[672:656552] [] tcp_timers tcp[2] retransmit SYN 5
    2018-07-18 12:03:53.291663+0400 AWR_Vehicle_Recieving[672:656552] [] tcp_timers tcp[3] retransmit SYN 5
    2018-07-18 12:03:55.041617+0400 AWR_Vehicle_Recieving[672:656591] [] tcp_timers tcp[2] retransmit SYN 6
    2018-07-18 12:03:55.298220+0400 AWR_Vehicle_Recieving[672:656591] [] tcp_timers tcp[3] retransmit SYN 6
    2018-07-18 12:03:59.048019+0400 AWR_Vehicle_Recieving[672:656549] [] tcp_timers tcp[2] retransmit SYN 7
    2018-07-18 12:03:59.304982+0400 AWR_Vehicle_Recieving[672:656549] [] tcp_timers tcp[3] retransmit SYN 7
    2018-07-18 12:04:00.003149+0400 AWR_Vehicle_Recieving[672:656478] Status bar could not find cached time string image. Rendering in-process.
    2018-07-18 12:04:07.054542+0400 AWR_Vehicle_Recieving[672:656552] [] tcp_timers tcp[2] retransmit SYN 8
    2018-07-18 12:04:07.314792+0400 AWR_Vehicle_Recieving[672:656552] [] tcp_timers tcp[3] retransmit SYN 8
    2018-07-18 12:04:23.061853+0400 AWR_Vehicle_Recieving[672:656552] [] tcp_timers tcp[2] retransmit SYN 9
    2018-07-18 12:04:23.327710+0400 AWR_Vehicle_Recieving[672:656552] [] tcp_timers tcp[3] retransmit SYN 9

2018-07-18 12:04:48.807451+0400 AWR_Vehicle_Recieving[672:656955] Task <4E4BA101-41B3-4A33-905F-9BC082F5B45B>.<1> finished with error - code: -1001
2018-07-18 12:04:48.825138+0400 AWR_Vehicle_Recieving[672:656955] Task <4E4BA101-41B3-4A33-905F-9BC082F5B45B>.<1> HTTP load failed (error code: -999 [1:89])
2018-07-18 12:04:48:826 AWR_Vehicle_Recieving[672:656880] Session task failed with error: Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1001 "The request timed out." UserInfo={NSUnderlyingError=0x1c084dda0 {Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1001 "(null)" UserInfo={_kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-2102, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=4}}, NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://cognito-identity.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/, NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://cognito-identity.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=4, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-2102, NSLocalizedDescription=The request timed out.}
```

I’m following the AWS Documentation, all the required details I gathered from AWS documentations only.

I've configured  my **info.plist** and also added **awrconfiguration.json** into my project.

I've mentioned the credentials in my AppDelegate Class:

```
AWSCognitoCredentialsProvider *credentialsProvider = [[AWSCognitoCredentialsProvider alloc]
                                                          initWithRegionType:AWSRegionAPSouth1
                                                          identityPoolId:@"ap-south-1:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx”];


    AWSServiceConfiguration *configuration = [[AWSServiceConfiguration alloc] initWithRegion:AWSRegionAPSouth1
                                                                         credentialsProvider:credentialsProvider];
    [AWSServiceManager defaultServiceManager].defaultServiceConfiguration = configuration;
```

I'm unable to understand what I'm doing wrong here as the code works fine in older versions of iOS.

My Other question is: If we really need to provide the credentials in the AppDelegate Class, then why do we need to configure info.plist or why need to copy awsconfiguration.json file into our project. What is the way to read the credentials from info.plist or read the awsconfiguration file programmatically, without defining credentials in the AppDelegate.m file ?

Answer (score 0):

This is a partial answer.

Hi,

First, to clear up the confusion. You only need one:

- `awsconfiguration.json`
- `Info.plist`
- Code based credentials in
  AppDelegate (or elsewhere)

Second, to access the configuration from either `awsconfiguration.json` -or- `Info.plist` you may construct:

`AWSS3TransferUtility *transferUtility = [AWSS3TransferUtility defaultS3TransferUtility];`

Can you try only the code based approach and reply here while I debug further?

Comment: Hi, Thank for clearing this up for me .

So you are saying I should remove the configuration from info.plist, also remove awsconfiguration.json from project and try again with the same code ?

I did that and it gave me the same error response.

Comment: Also, I tried different approach to upload the file. Previously I was using

    `AWSS3TransferManager *transferManager = [AWSS3TransferManager defaultS3TransferManager];`

And now I tried 
`AWSS3TransferUtility *transferUtility = [AWSS3TransferUtility defaultS3TransferUtility];`

But it gave me the same error response.

Also, after removing the awrconfiguration.json file, one message is being printed in the logs
`Couldn't locate the awsconfiguration.json file. Skipping load of awsconfiguration.json.`
I believe, it is not causing any issue.

Comment: Sorry for reporting this late, actually it was an IP issues, AWS tends to change the range of IPs from time to time (Security issues may be) for uploading the files on S3 bucket. I just whitelisted that range of IPs in my network and it worked.

Also, my both iPad were on different networks, one with open network and the other one with private network.